# How can I make ack search in "Gemfile"?

Tags: ack, gemfile

Does anyone know how to make "ack" to search in such files like "Gemfile"?

Just adding `--type-add=ruby=Gemfile` to "~/.ackrc" doesn't work because "Gemfile" doesn't have any file extension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's right.  Ack 1.x does not support detecting filetypes on files that don't have an extension.  This will change in ack 2.0.  http://github.com/petdance/ack2 is where we're working on it.